# Duplicate UIImageView when in landscape orientation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, orientation

I think i'm going crazy, as this seems like an incredibly easy issue to solve, but:

I have the following:

```
    UIImageView *bird = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, -150, 50, 67)];
bird.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
[bird setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tinylogo_night.png"]];
[scrollView addSubview:bird];
```

It works fine in portrait orientation, but in landscape orientation the image is at the original coordinates as well as the place where the flexible margins put it. What in the world am i not realizing here?

Edit: Here's the rest:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll_iPhone:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
CGRect frm = navBar.frame;
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
frm.origin.y = -58-offset.y;
navBar.frame = frm;

if (dropdownBar && dropdownBarVisible) {
    // MAYBETODO dynamically calculate position relative to navbar
    frm = dropdownBar.frame;
    frm.origin.y = -1-offset.y;
    dropdownBar.frame = frm;
}
//scientific pulldown image
UIImageView *bird = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, -150, 50, 67)];
[bird setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tinylogo_night.png"]];
[scrollView addSubview:bird];
//end pulldown image
```

}

Comment: What method is this code from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be adding another `UIImageView` subview to your scroll view every time you receive the `scrollViewDidScroll_iPhone:` message.  That really doesn't sound like something you want to do.

Comment: ooh... no it's not... how do i fix that?

Comment: Add the subview somewhere else that only runs once.  The `viewDidLoad` method would probably be a good place.

Comment: and fixed! Thanks a lot :) It's a bit late in the night so pardon my derpness.